# Who were the belligerent factions of World War III?

Tags: star-trek

In the Star Trek universe, it's not completely clear to me who the belligerent factions of World War III were.  Who were they and what is known about them?

Comment: Skynet and OCP, obviously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to shamelessly steal from [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/World_War_III):

> Among the parties involved was the Eastern Coalition (also referred to as "the ECON"), whose direct attacks included those against the United States of America. (Star Trek: First Contact) In 2026, at the start of the war, Colonel Phillip Green led a faction of eco-terrorists that was responsible for the loss of 37 million lives. (TOS: "Bread and Circuses", "The Savage Curtain"; ENT: "In a Mirror, Darkly, Part II")

---

**NON-canon material** (books) elaborates. From [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/World_War_III):

> One side was composed of the United States and the European Union; the other side was an alliance known as the Eastern Coalition.
>
> The detonation of nuclear weapons over cities such as London, New York City, Tel Aviv, Jerusalem, Mecca, Riyadh, Karachi, and New Delhi killed nearly half a billion people instantly.
>
> During fighting in Paris during the war, the Eiffel Tower was destroyed. (DS9 novel: Trapped in Time)

So, it was US, EU (obviously new to the material since the age of Roddenberry) - including at least UK and France, India and Israel all involved on one side.

---

Please note that there just aren't all that many details known about WWIII in Star Trek:

> ... very few details have been presented in Star Trek on World War III. In 1996, this event received a Trekker's Choice Award for the 'Oft Heard but Never Seen' Award, as being "the favorite historical moment only alluded to in Star Trek."

Comment: How shameless of you!

Comment: This is why I asked the question, surely it was more than just an Eastern Coalition attacking the U.S. with some eco terrorists thrown in.  Surely the U.S. was allied with someone, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Caimen - from the same article: "Like the Earth-Romulan War, very few details have been presented in Star Trek on World War III. In 1996, this event received a Trekker's Choice Award for the 'Oft Heard but Never Seen' Award, as being "the favorite historical moment only alluded to in Star Trek."

Comment: @Caimen - done.

Comment: We should differentiate between the Eugenics Wars and World War III which are different wars.  The Eugenics Wars happened between 1992 and 1996 while World War III was between 2026 and 2053.  Technically all current real world history has been altered and we can no longer infer that history is the same since 1992 in the Star Trek universe.

Comment: @Caimen One of the novels has retconned the Eugenics Wars into a behind-the-scenes struggle that was the cause of all the civil unrest in the 90s.  Meaning it _could_ have still happened.

Comment: @DVK Two things I was trying to get at, I don't see any of the cited material in the Memory Beta link, the Memory Beta links to the Eugenics wars and not WWIII.

Comment: @Caimen - Sorry, that was me pasting wrong link (to memory Alpha, to boot). Fixed